# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter in electron node native module disables crash reporter

Tags: c++, node.js, electron, native-module

I have a native node module running in an electron application and I want to log all unhandled exceptions so I use the following snippet:

```
LONG WINAPI unhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS)
{
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER; // 1
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION; // 2
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH; // 3
}

SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(unhandledExceptionFilter);
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(0, unhandledExceptionFilter);
```

The problem is that when I use *SetUnhandledExceptionFilter* electron crash reporting will not work anymore (I have it set up to send a log file to some server). I also tried all possible return values but none work.

What am I doing wrong ? and how to get this to work ?

Some more info:

- Window 7 64 bit
- Application is 32bit
- Electron version 1.7.10
- Node version 8.1.3
- [Electron crash reporter](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/atom/common/crash_reporter/crash_reporter_win.cc)

Comment: Unclear: which of the 3 `return` lines  do you actually use?

Comment: "I also tried all possible return values but none work."